# Вопрос по substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

Как показать информацию на нескольких страницах
с помощью `substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Есть код

```
  <?php 
  if (substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page1/' или '/page2/')) { ?> текст <?php }
  else { ?> текст <?php }
  ?>
```

Как вставить условие ИЛИ?

Comment: Никак `preg_match('/\\/(page1|page2)\\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` вам в помощь

Comment: @Mike думаю следует уточнить, куда совать этот прегматч. А то ведь ТС попробует его в `substr_count` запихнуть

Comment: какой фреймворк или cms используете? Для чпу есть специальные функции для получения параметров у таких систем даже в рукописном варианте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr_count` может искать только одну строку. Для поиска различных совпадений проще использовать [регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и функцию [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php). Например так:

```
<?php 
 if (preg_match('/\\/(page1|page2)\\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { ?> текст <?php }
 else { ?> текст <?php }
?>
```

или даже так:

```
if (preg_match('/\\/page[12]\\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```